# how to replicate onGestureEvent onBegin action using useAnimatedGestureHandler

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-reanimated, react-native-gesture-handler

I need my gesture handler to respond as soon as a user puts his thumb down on the screen, actually onStart only fires when the thumb starts moving right or left. How can I dot this? Thank you.

```
const onGestureEvent = useAnimatedGestureHandler({
        onStart: () => {
            isActive.value = true;
        },
        onActive: (event) => {
            ...
        },
        onEnd: () => {
            isActive.value = false;
        },
  });
```